# Need help deploying Vue Laravel SPA in a shared hosting

Tags: laravel, vue.js, deployment, hosting, single-page-application

I finished developing a Single Page Application using Vue Js in the front end to consume the APIs that I built with Laravel in the backend 
I already deployed an old Laravel-only App in my shared hosting but now with all the new js files and node modules I have no idea what to do 
I can't find any good tutorial or article, your help will be so much appreciated!
ps: I am using webpack to mix my SPA files

Comment: You need to give some more details. Do you use webpack to build the SPA? I also strongly advice to use a small VPS. That gives you much more control (which can be done using Laralvel Forge if you are unfamiliar with devops).

Comment: thanks for your replay, yes I use Webpack to build the SPA, unfortunately, all I have available now is shared hosting and I need to deploy my app in it, any Idea ?

Comment: You could use a symlink to point to this directory, assuming you've got a `dist` directory.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to deploy vue app in the shared hosting environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47327621/how-to-deploy-vue-app-in-the-shared-hosting-environment)